# jquery each of json object does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array and ajax function. I'm adding the objects into array.

```
var names = [];
...
success: function(msg){
    for (var i in msg.response.pipelines){
        for (var j in msg.response.pipelines[i].statuses){
            names.push({
              pipeline: msg.response.pipelines[i].name,
              item: msg.response.pipelines[i].statuses[j].name
            });
        }
    }
```

Then I see in console `console.log(names)`

[image: Array of objects]

Then I'm trying to get "item" and "pipeline" from array.

```
console.log(names.length); // give 0
$.each(names, function (key) {
        console.log('123');
        console.log(key.item + ' - ' + key.pipeline);
    })
```

But I'm getting nothing as if the function does not exist...

Comment: is there any error in console or whats after 123 undefined or anythin?

Comment: Can you post the `JSON`, not just the image?

Comment: I wonder if you're trying to process `names` before the request has executed.

Comment: There are no '123' in console..

Comment: Names are an empty array until callback promise will be resolved. This is async.

Comment: Did you check the raw response? Maybe it does not contain expected array values and dimensions. I like using Chrome for Javascript-Debugging. Just break in the first line of "success" and inspect "msg".

Comment: Łukasz, you're right, but "success" should be a "complete" method so the async call should have finished. Talking about "async": Please, everyone, never ever turn off async, every async problem can be handled programmatically ;-)

Comment: names.length give me 0..

Comment: Something must be happening between the `console.log(names)` and the `console.log(names.length)`. Maybe some other piece of code is doing things in between. Take into account also the following: your console shows the list of names but on the top it says `Array[0]`. As I have experienced, some browsers show the object in its final state in debugger even if you console.log it at the beginning. Could be that names is empty when it reaches the `each` bit and later on gets populated. On the console you may be seeing names in its final state and not how it was when you console.log it.

Answer (score 1):

I think `msg` in `success: function( msgs )` is not ab object but an array.

`pipelines` is also not an array but a string. so you can't use `pipelines[i]`

you can use

```
for (var i in msg){
    console.log( msg[i].pipelines );
}
```

or I suggest you to use like

```
success: function(msg){

    $.each( msg, function( index, item ) {

          console.log( item ) // this will be { "item" : "xxxx", "pipeline" : "xxxxxxxxxx"}
          // Now check what you want to do

    } );
} );
```

Comment: missing an argument for `$.each()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use key with the actual array in your function

```
    $.each(names, function (key) {
        console.log('123');
        console.log(names[key].item + ' - ' + names[key].pipeline);
    })
```

Should work.

Alternatively you need to add a variable for the value:

```
    $.each(names, function (key, value) {
        console.log('123');
        console.log(value.item + ' - ' + value.pipeline);
    })
```

Comment: `names.length = 0` so it does not iterate anyway

Comment: Yeah, missed that bit. Presumably an async problem of some kind then.